# Como importar arquivo .dat para o R

Tags: r

Baixei um arquivo .dat que e basicamente uma matriz com dados.

No entanto, me parece que a unica forma de trabalhar com ele é fazendo o seguinte comando (Estou o usando o R e não tenho muita experiencia com o R):

```
   setwd("C:")
    load("dat73_1")
```

Depois desse comando "load" esse arquivo fica "escondido" pelo R??

O código que se faz para ler esse arquivo é o seguinte:

```
mylist<-c("CAN","FRA","DEU","ITA","JPN","GBR","G6")
```

Se eu quiser as informações referente a "CAN", é so modificar "`cno in 1:7`" para "`cno in 1:1`".

```
  for (cno in 1:7){
      init_date<-c(1973,3)
      start_date <- init_date+c(6,3)
      end_date<-c(2009,10) 
      country<-mylist[cno]
      Cdat<-data.frame(window(ts(get(country),start=init_date,freq=12),start=start_date, end=end_date))}
```

Eu fiz isso e consegui recuperar esse arquivo para todos os paises do `mylist` e criei um novo arquivo em Excel. Mas não consigo adaptar o codigo ao arquivo em excel. Há como fazer isso?

Se eu conseguir "achar" esse arquivo .dat tbm ajudaria bastante.

OBS (Editado):
Quando utilizo o comando read.table a saida é essa (RStudio):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para ler arquivos dat, você usa a função read.table(file). Só verifica se precisa usar outros argumentos, tais como header=T, se você quiser os nomes originais das colunas e skip=número de linhas as serem evitadas. Os arquivos dat têm geralmente informações extra, então o argumento skip serve para ignorá-las.

Comment: @José obrigada!. Eu editei o topico para mostrar a saida qdo eu uso o comando read.table. Não consigo puxar direito.

Comment: 1) De onde conseguistes este arquivo? Na fonte não havia nenhuma informação sobre separador ou como ler o arquivo? 2) O comando `load()` deve ser usado em arquivos binários do `R`com extensão `.RDA` ou `.Rdata`, não deve ser o que precisas.

Comment: Olá, @Laura. Você sabe que programa gerou esse arquivo `.data`? Pelo que vi do resultado após usar o `read.table()` me parece que seu arquivo é binário (porém não no formato `.RData`, que poderia ser lido pela função `load()`). Arquivos assim geralmente exigem um tratamento fora do R para que sejam convertidos em uma tabela de dados em formato `.csv` ou `.txt`, por exemplo. Somente depois é que podem ser lidos com a função `read.table()` dentro do R.

Comment: posta o arquivo aqui de exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ler diretamente com a base do R usando `read.delim()`:

```
dados <- read.delim("arquivo.dat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir arquivos no formato ".dta" uma outra alternativa é usar o pacote haven. Em seguida, procure a função read_dta.

```
install.packages("haven")
library("haven")
read_dta()
```

Comment: `.dat` e `.dta` são formatos diferentes